# Django-CMS Type Error "a float is required"

Tags: python, django, deployment, django-cms, bluehost

I'm deploying my first Django app on a BlueHost shared server. It is a simple site powered by Django-CMS, and portions of it are working, however there are some deal-breaking quirks.

A main recurring one reads `TypeError`, `a float is required`. The exception location each time is `.../python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 391`. For example, I run into it when trying to load a page which includes `{% cms_toolbar %}` in the template, pressing "save and continue editing" when creating a page, or trying to delete a page through the admin interface.

I don't know if this is related, but nothing happens when I select a plugin from the "Available Plugins" drop-down while editing a page and press "Add Plugin".

Has anyone had any experience with this error, or have any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: What version of Django CMS are you using? I've seen some 500 errors on Ajax posts when adding content plugins via Firebug that took some work to fix in earlier versions.

Comment: Django CMS version 2.4.2, Django 1.5.1. Everything is the latest version through pip.

Interestingly, when I went in through Firefox to check with Firebug, the CSS for the admin interface didn't load quite right but it went along with adding a plugin right until I pressed "save", when the same error popped up.

Comment: have you submitted this as an issue at https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues ?

Comment: No, I figured this was an issue with my configuration not with Django-CMS. Do I still submit there?

Comment: I can't decipher the function that is raising the error, but I see it has to do with URLs. Could the issue be that I am accessing the site through my temporary URL for BlueHost, and by accessing the FCGI script directly? (Both problems I am fixing presently.) The format for the link is 'ip_address/~username/mysite.fcgi'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wondered, the problem was that I was accessing the site using my temporary link from BlueHost, which the function throwing the error could not handle.

When my clients finally pointed their domain name at the server this problem and a few others (CSS inconsistencies in the Django admin, trouble with .htaccess) disappeared. Everything is up now and working fine.